# Popup don't present content only a blank screen

Tags: javascript, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, 32-bit

I am trying to make a JavaScript popup which function on IE8 32 bits, the following examples run without any problem on several browsers including IE8 64 bits on the same computer

[pop up examples](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/creating_opening_new_window_pop_ups_javascript.php3)

On IE8 32 bits everything results in a blank screen with a spinning mouse icon, what should I do to make my JavaScript run on IE8.

```
window.open("http://google.com",'popup_window','width=810,height=480,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes')
```

The exact problem is described in this thread
[ie8 wont load popup links](http://www.sevenforums.com/browsers-mail/11343-ie8-wont-load-popup-links.html)

Comment: I think this is due to security settings. Do you get an error message in the console?

Comment: No error message in the console

Comment: FYI do the same for URLMon.dll fixed my blank pop issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly fix the problem when you re-register IEPROXY.DLL everything start working as designed

- clicking **START --> RUN**
- typing **regsvr32 IEPROXY.DLL**
- And then clicking **OK**.